# Regarding reboot problem

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8, reboot

I have been installing Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 8.1. after completion of whole the process of installation, I was not able to find "dual os selection" dialog. Every time it show normal booting of window. inspite of installation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have installed the operating systems in the wrong order. Windows will carelessly overwrite the boot sector. Please see this [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tutorial. That should do the trick.